# SomeCoCMISDataCreator example not working

Tags: alfresco

check out the source from content-model and running examples .we are using 5.1.1 version.SomeCoCMISDataCreator admin admin SomeCo whitepaper test.

https://github.com/jpotts/alfresco-developer-series/tree/master/content

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisObjectNotFoundException: Object not found: /SomeCo
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:473)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.read(AbstractAtomPubService.java:619)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.getObjectInternal(AbstractAtomPubService.java:842)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.ObjectServiceImpl.getObjectByPath(ObjectServiceImpl.java:628)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.getObjectByPath(SessionImpl.java:554)
```

Comment: What folder are you trying to create the sample data in? And did you make sure it exists?

Comment: I didnt create any folder before running this class.Do I need create the "SomeCo" folder;If yes then where to create?These are the args passing to this class SomeCoCMISDataCreator "admin admin SomeCo whitepaper test"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log in to Alfresco Share as admin, click "Repository", click "Create Folder" and create a folder named "SomeCo".